# Cannot consume webservice over ssl

Tags: c#, web-services, security, ssl, pkcs#12

I am trying to consume webservice over https protocol. I have password-protected p12 file with certificate. After importing this file I can view service methods over browser and I can add service as a ServiceReference in VisualStudio client application. Problem appears while invoking methods of this service. I tried almost everything and still get error 'Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority {server_name}'.
What can be wrong?

Comment: Have you used the NetworkCredential class for authenthication? http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.net.networkcredential%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: no, I do not need credentials

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least few possible causes but I would start by redefining the certificate validation callback:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (a,b,c,d) => true;
```

Put this like in your client code before you access the service.